# Suddenly, I can not run python code

Tags: python

Suddenly, I am not able to run python code for .py files that are placed in a folder inside c:/python33

I tried to create a new .py file that only contains this procedure:

```
def myproc(): 
    print( 'hi')
```

When try to run it, I get:

```
>>> from test import myproc
>>> myproc
<function myproc at 0x000000000298A1E0>
```

I tried to run another codes placed in c:/python but in another folder, and it runs fine without any problem.

I also tried to copy the problematic folder and delete the old one, but still can not run any .py file inside that problematic folder.

Can you advise me what is the problem ? How to solve it ?

Comment: Don't call your moulde `test`. There is [a package from the Python standard library](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/test.html) with this name.

Comment: And don't put your application in the distribution directory. Assuming that `c:\python33` is where Python lives, which is the default installation directory.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a specific coding bug of the OP. 'too localized'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to *call* the function, not just *reference* it. Replace:

```
myproc
```

With:

```
myproc()
```

Adding parenthesis calls the function. When you reference it you are shown the representation of the function. That is why you get `<function myproc at blah>`.

Comment: Shame on me. How did I miss something like that.

Answer (score 0):

without parenthesis you're just referring to the function pointer.
as said above you need parenthesis to actually call it.